# How do I change an attribute of another object in Aframe?

Tags: aframe

In Javascript I would do parent.document.sphere1.setAttribute('color','blue');
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah.

`document.querySelector('a-sphere').setAttribute('color', 'blue');

https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/guides/using-javascript-and-dom-apis.html

Comment: Thanks, Kevin. I'm there now working through the docs. I did get the simple log example to display in the console but once I tried to display data from the scene and from the ID #Redbox example I see no data. I guess the example assumes something that I don't know? Maybe I missed something? Am I supposed to see data in the form of a string? 

Wish an example was there like the log example. This is what I meant in my email. If an example of 'full" code was given no mistakes would be made like I'm making now.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using Kevin's Component here (he offered the idea): 
[https://github.com/ngokevin/aframe-event-set-component][1]

Then, follow his instructions or add the javascript to the head of your html page and add similar code to this:

```
<a-image id="map1" src="img/map.png" position="0 14 0" rotation="0 -60 0" height="1" width=".5" scale="6 6 6"
event-set__1="_event: click; _target: #mycamera; position: 0 0 -18;"
event-set__2="_event: click; _target: #secondfloor1; visible: true;"
event-set__3="_event: mouseenter; _target: #archiveTxt; visible: true;"
event-set__4="_event: mouseleave; _target: #archiveTxt; visible: false;">
</a-image>
```

For moving the camera or teleporting just give your camera the id="myCamera".
Still can't figure out animation with this but it's a great start. event-set numbers must be in order like above.